# svm - num of samples and learn matrix

Tags: python, svm

1. Sklearn.svm.SVC says "The fit time complexity is more than quadratic with the number of samples which makes it hard to scale to dataset with more than a couple of 10000 samples."
   My dataset has over 30,000 samples, how can I avoid these hard computations?
   Can SVC method parameters/ estimator/ cross validation help me in this case?
2. My data set isn't n*n matrix, does fit method takes this under consideration, or should I do something in regard?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's clarify a few things? Is your training data set 30,000 samples? What do you mean by your data set is not an N*N matrix? It rarely is right, it should be a vector (per sample) of vectors (of data-points). If that's what you are going to be passing in, there should be no problem if your number of samples is different than the dimensionality of your data)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.
Each sample has N attributes, but M is the number of samples.
And for the first question, I have more than 30,000 vectors,
is there something I can do with it?

Comment: The only thing the docs are saying is that it's a very large dataset that could take forever to calculate. Slice your training data and see how long it takes on 10,000 samples, and this should give you an idea of whether it would work on the whole training data.

Comment: What do you mean? I guess it will work, but it would yield less accurate results.
Anyway, I thought of slicing the data, however I will have to "learn" 3 times,
and then I am not sure of what I am supposed to do.

Thanks again :)